# How can I install MiKTeX packages that are not found in the Package Manager?

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MikTex (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I am new to LaTeX and looking to convert my undergraduate thesis to LaTeX format for practice. [This community wiki answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis/914#914) suggests that a document class `puthesis` from Purdue University would be a good starting point.

I already know how to install packages using the MiKTeX Package Manager. However, I could not find `puthesis` there. Also, I could not find beginner-class instructions on the [`puthesis` page](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/)

Comment: Please have a look at the possible duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows - look at the section "Installing sty or cls files" since the puthesis package consists of such files.

Comment: Unless there is an objection I'll close this as a dup later on today: it seems there is agreement (neither Stefan or I can vote to close without it happening!)