# Lyx Templates site

Tags: templates, lyx

Does anyone know of a site which collates Lyx templates and provides previews of how they look?
I don't just mean thesis layouts but also letters, essays and all sorts. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

There are many examples in the LyX wiki: http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Examples. Among them are letters, presentations, CV, exercises and more.
Or check out the [Layouts](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Layouts) page on the same site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that list of examples is very poorly presented. Are there any other sources of templates?

Comment: I don't know a better presented LyX templates/examples site. It would be great if somebody knows one or creates one. Btw. some LyX (but thesis) templates have been mentioned on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis