# Making a math poster using LyX

Tags: lyx, beamerposter

Is there a Beamer for LyX (or something analogous so that I can make a poster)? A code for a sample poster would be great.

If so, can one please leave some details on how I would go about adding this (I.e. do I add something to my LateX preamble, do I download a package)?

Related Questions:

- Given a LateX source code, how do I enter this into LyX? I know how to turn my work into a LateX source, but I do not know how to do the opposite.
- I also have MikTeX. I am not sure if Beamer can be used directly on that, but if it is possible, please give some details.
- Does one turn the code/work into a PDF before making it a poster? If not, what would I convert my material to before I print out a poster? I have access to a facility that will print out the poster.
- If I'm not supposed to use PDF for the poster, is there a way to see what my current work looks like?

**Edit**

After downloading the link sciposter.lyx in the "tread" in the comment below given by dcmst, I wanted to see what the sample looked like in PDF, but I got this error. [image]

Comment: you can find an example in this [thread](http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/a0poster-example-using-LyX-td479681.html).

Comment: @dcmst might be suggesting about [sciposter](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sciposter).

Comment: Did you install [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) or [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) on the computer `sciposter.cls` is part of both LaTeX distributions. [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717)

Comment: type at commandline window to verify if you have sciposter installed or not using `kpsewhich sciposter.cls`, if not install using package manager as show in my answer.

Comment: In case you were looking for what I was looking for (a no-hassle working lyx file), they recently put one up in the [LyX repository](http://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=blob;f=lib/examples/beamerposter.lyx;h=f6e980fab6e825d99de7505e52c8fe1978e84756;hb=master).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Though it is written for LaTeX (but LyX generates LaTeX), all the information in "[How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)" might be a good starting point to get some impression what is possible.
2. Possibly, with the package "beamerposter" you can use "beamer"...
3. In the end (after setting up and writing your document), you can create a PDF file as usual. So you will definitely get a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers and comments here.

1) I am not aware of Lyx editor,[Lyx Templates site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5708/15717), [Writing posters with beamerposter package in LaTeX](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/shang/shang.pdf) would be good start point.

2) Yes,you can use beamer on MiKTeX. Run commandwindow `cmd` from `start programs menu` and type `kpsewhich beamer.cls beamerposter.sty` at command prompt to verify the installation of `beamer.cls` and `beamerposter.sty`.

If you have it then you see the path of files, in any case MiKTeX has automatic package installation when you start compiling the beamerposter document code. If automatic package installation fails use [MiKTeX package manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) to install any package and [Update your MiKTeX distribution to latest package version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473/15717)

3) [beamerposter](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamerposter) as mentioned by e-birk & others has all poster sizes ranging [A0->A4 poster size ratios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A_size_illustration2_with_letter_and_legal.svg). For getting started with beamerposter example see [author's page](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php#example) or [ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamerposter/example.tex)

4) The source `beamerposter-example.tex` is converted to `beamerposter- example.pdf` (A0 or A3 size)depending on option for example: `\usepackage[size=a0]{beamerposter}`in  poster size requirement.

Change option to `size=a4` size (for draft and avoid paper waste) and `size=a4` sheet once it's final. Otherwise use the same A0-poster.pdf to print on A4 paper by selecting the printer paper size options. You don't need anything more documents except `.tex` for code and `.pdf` for printing once `beamer.cls` and beamerposter.sty` is installed. Hope this helps you get started.