# How does \include work in terms of preamble? And is \input better?

Tags: chapters, include, preamble

When you have different files; say different chapters of a book, that are written in separate Tex files, all having their own preamble packages and document class options, how does it work when you `\include` them in one file with its own preamble options. Do they use the root file preamble alone for things like `\title` or `a4paper,openleft` options? Do different options and packages add up from different files?

I also understand that `\input` uses the preamble of the root file alone, is this true? and if so, would that make it better than `\include`; as in easier to manage?

Comment: `\include` and `\input` don't differ as regards the presence of a document preamble. In a file that's read in with either `\input` or `\include`, there *mustn't* be a `\begin{document}` or a `\documentclass` command (with one exception, but it's not important), unless you use the facility which Counter Terrorist pointed to.

Comment: `docmute` package and `combine` documentclass might be useful as well.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40144/how-to-use-inputfile-tex-correctly/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certain commands are only allowed in a document preamble. For example, if you use `\usepackage{<package>}` within the `document` environment, LaTeX conveniently "suggests" the obvious:

> LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

And, since both `\input{<file>}` and `\include{<file>}` do very similar things - including the contents of `<file>` in your document (the latter is a little more elaborate) - you can't include a full-fledged or stand-alone document with its own document class and preamble via `\input` or `\include` without some help. Nor will preambles be interlaced sequentially. The difference is explained in [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Your only solution is to use a package or document class that can handle (circumvent) this restriction. Options include the [`subfiles` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) (not distributed with TeX Live), [`combine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) or the [`standalone` package/class](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone).

A good place to start is [Make a .tex file that combines complete .tex documents in subdirectories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21997/5764). The main idea is that you have a master (or main) file that covers all the sub-file preambles and requirements, since the sub-file preambles will be lost at the time of inclusion.

Comment: So you could say that one could use `\include` to separate different included "chapters", add repeatedly used commands with `\insert`, use the `standalone` package to strip all preambles from sub-files OR use `subpreambles` to combine all the preambles from the sub-files into the root file. Right?

Comment: @AymanElmasry: You should read the [`standalone` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) and/or the [`subfiles` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) and follow the instructions given in either, depending on your choice. What do you use `\insert` for?

Comment: Oops, I meant `\input`. Sorry.