# Interpreting a part of a code

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following code for header definition:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\emph{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\emph{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=42}{\strong{--~\reflectbox{\thepage}~--}}{\strong{--~\thepage~--}}} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\ifthenelse{\value{page}=42}{\strong{--~\reflectbox{\thepage}~--}}{\strong{--~\thepage~--}}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

Now, I've compiled my .tex file with this code and without the `\ifthenelse` part, and I don't see any difference. Now my document still doesn't have 42 pages, and I see that it mentions this here, and I'm wondering what does it do?

I used a template from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9931/headings-and-advice-to-write-a-phd-in-physics-using-latex) question.

Comment: on page 42 it writes the page number using mirror writing

Comment: Just that? What's the usage of mirror writing of page numbers?

Comment: someone's joke presumably:-)

Comment: lol So I can safely remove that part of code :D Thanks

Comment: Ofc I know of 42 xD But I didn't understand what the author wanted with this (wasn't aware of the joke)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 42 it writes the page number using mirror writing