# LaTeX templates bundled with MikTeX or elsewhere?

Tags: templates, examples

Q: Where can I find generic LaTeX document templates (e.g., for the `article`, `book`, etc., classes)? Are there any bundled in MikTeX? Elsewhere?

I've found a number of posts answering this question for more specific classes (e.g., [Thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis)) but not much for the general classes.

The Beamer class comes packaged with a number of template and example `.tex` files which I use extensively. Unfortunately, I can't find any equivalent to this for more general classes.

Comment: `sample2e` is a very simple example for beginners, `small2e` is even smaller. They are distributed with LaTeX2e kernel. But I don't think they are good *templates*.

Comment: Your question is pretty general, and it might help to describe a little more what you want. For example, some subject areas have more definite requirements than others.

Comment: @Leo: Thank you. This is sort of what I was looking for. Would be nice if MikTeX bundled general templates/examples that were more extensive, like the Beamer class' templates/examples. I'll just start building my own gradually.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm just looking for general templates like the ones @Leo mentioned (more extensive would be nice) or like the ones found packaged with the Beamer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent MiKTeX distributions comes with TeXworks. It has some templates built in, which can be accesses from 'New from template ...' on the File menu of the program. You could take a look there: there is nothing to stop you simply saving the templates and then looking at them in your favoured editor.

Comment: That's kind of cool. Didn't know about that---since I've been using WinEdt. Certainly helps a little bit.