# Compile multiple .tex files to one file

Tags: multiple-files, document-size

I am making a math formulary collection but the file is getting too big and too long!
So i was wondering if it is possible to make a .tex for for multiplication and one .tex file for division. And then make a third .tex file where i am importing the other two files and still be able to make TOC?
and lets say each .tex files also have multiple sections and sub(sub)sections

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29577/2975)

Answer (score 3):

In order to selectively include parts of your document and still get page numbers and table of contents right, you can use `\include` and `\includeonly`.  Your main file should look like this:

```
\documentclass{whatever}
% put preamble here

% \includeonly{mult}
% \includeonly{div}
% \includeonly{mult,div}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{mult}
\include{div}
\end{document}
```

The files `mult.tex` and `div.tex` should then only contain the corresponding text and formulas, but no preamble (no `documentclass`, no `\begin{document}`, etc.).

Note that `\include` always starts a new page.  This is necessary in order to get consistent layout and page numbers.  On the other hand, `\input` does not insert a new page, but then you do not get the right table of contents, and page numbers change when you comment out one of the files.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! I have edited the last line in the Question, i hope you have a great anwser for that

Comment: No problem with that.  Just put the `\section` and `\subsection` commands into your files `mult.tex` and `div.tex`.

Comment: A good read about `\input` vs. `\include` is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2975

Answer (score 3):

Applying "divide and conquer" approach to your project -- by splitting your project into several smaller input files -- is a good practice.

In addition to this, it will be better if you can compile each smaller input file so you can see the result on which you focus. Compiling each smaller input file, of course, takes shorter time compared to compiling the project as a whole.

The following imitates your case. Consider you have 2 smaller input files called `dif.tex` and `int.tex`. Both are compilable as follows.

## `dif.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Definition}
\[
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)
\]

\section{Partial differentiation}
\[
\textrm{d}(AB) = B\,\textrm{d}A +A\,\textrm{d}B
\]
\end{document}
```

## `int.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Definite integral}
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a)
\]

\section{Partial integral}
\[
\int A\, \textrm{d}B = AB -\int B \, \textrm{d}A
\]
\end{document}
```

Now you can import both smaller files from your main input file (called `main.tex`) as follows. Note that we need to load `docmute` in the `main.tex`. The purpose of this package is to make `\input` only import contents between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

## `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\input{dif}
\input{int}

\end{document}
```

## Update based on the additional comments

If your project is structured as follows,

```
.../main/main.tex
.../main/dif/dif.tex
.../main/int/int.tex
```

The `main.tex` has to be slightly modified as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\input{dif/dif}
\input{int/int}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if i have main.tex in a folder called main and then dif.tex in a subfolder named dif (/main/dif/dif.tex. How could I then import dif.?

Answer (score 1):

You could organize your material in three separate files:

- File `mult.tex`: Just the body of the multiplication-related material, no preamble, no `\begin{document}`, and no `\end{document}`.
- File `div.tex`: Just the body of the division-related material, no preamble, no `\begin{document}`, and no `\end{document}`.
- File `driver.tex`, organized as follows:

  ```
  \documentclass[<options, if any>]{article} % or `report`, or `book`, etc
  ... % preamble material, such as page size, etc
  \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \input mult
  \clearpage
  \input div
  \end{document}
  ```

If you want to compile just the `mult` material, or just the `div` material, comment out one of the other `\input` statements, and be sure to recompile twice in order to propagate all changes (including the table of contents).

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! I have edited the last line in the Question, i hope you have a great anwser for that

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes - There would be no problem at all with the files `mult.tex` and `div.tex` containing `\section`, `\subsection`, etc directives. If, say, `div.tex` comes after `mult.tex` in the driver file, and if you want to compile just `div.tex` while keeping its main section number at `2`, all you'd need to do is provide the instruction `\addtocounter{section}{1}` just ahead of `\input div`.