# How to deal with big documents?

Tags: compiling, document-size

I'm writing my PhD thesis using `LaTeX`. The text is becoming bigger and I'd like to know the `LaTeX` experts' opinion. What's the best way to deal with a big document and why? A single `.tex` file (`thesis.tex`) or divide the document in smaller `.tex` files, like `introduction.tex`, `materials.tex`, `results.tex`, etc. and compile with something like:

```
\documentclass[<options>]{<document type>}
\usepackage{<packages used>}
\begin{document}
\input{introduction}
\input{materials}
\input{results}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would that be the LaTeX expert's opinion or the LaTeX experts' opinions? Note that questions which ask primarily for opinions or whose answers can only be of this kind are off-topic for this site. In this non-expert's opinion, you should use `\include` so that `\includeonly` is available.

Comment: I think this question has been asked on this site before, let's find the duplicate questions.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I was looking for them. I'm sure it has been answered multiple times, in fact ....

Comment: This question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142417/what-are-your-best-practices-to-compile-only-a-part-of-the-document-or-presentat?rq=1, and the ones linked in it, seem pretty relevant.

Comment: For example [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files) asks why split a large file into separate files (though personally I find neither of the two answers is convincing). So I guess we can say that's the recommendation, there's no new question here.

Comment: one could do worse than follow the recommendations in this book: "[Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html)"

Comment: Additionally if you use bibliography engine and have to use a lot of cross-references, invoking `biber`, `makeindex`, `makeglossaries` and such, aside from `pdflatex`/`xelatex`, I would suggest to use a `latexmk` script that can save a lot of time during compilation by skipping unnecessary steps in your build chain.

Comment: @andselisk Only if you otherwise invoke the whole chain ;). For most people, it increases compilation time because `latexmk` thinks they need a new index or whatever, when they really don't. At least, this is why I avoid it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can we close a question as a duplicate of a book?

Comment: @cfr -- don't know the answer to your question, but i think the original question calls for an opinion and would be closable on that ground.  (and my comment gives *my* opinion.)  i don't think the "duplicate" really answers the original question though; it just applies an opinion assumed by those who voted to close.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed. Although it may be a matter of opinion where matters of opinion end and best practices begin.