# Does splitting tex documents into multiple ones improve build performance

Tags: input, include, workflow, performance

I've seen this mentioned often, for example, in several answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files). But I have my doubts. Do LaTeX engines (`latex/pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex`) do incremental compilation at all? Besides, even if they do, any file included in the main tex file with `\input{}` could redefine macros used in later included files, so how would the engines know when to recompile a partial file?

Comment: As you can see in the answer that you are referring to, it speeds up the compilation if you do compile selectively: "For one thing you can significantly speed up compilation time by including only certain files, e.g. when you have tons of graphics." **So it's easier to comment out parts temporarily for example.**

Comment: Elaborating on @Dr.ManuelKuehner ' s comment: I think the primary reason for splitting (large) documents into pieces is to create a good workflow, allowing you to focus intellectual attention on one part of the document at a time. Speeding up the build is a secondary benefit. Check out questions with the workflow tag.

Comment: it only speeds things up during drafts when you can make partial documents. If you are making a full document then it can not speed things up at all

Comment: Related: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/246)

Comment: Are there still open questions?

Comment: I find it sad that there's no reaction from your side at all after people investing time in your question.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: There is no direct answer to my question. Only comments.

Comment: That was absolutely not my point.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know if an `\input` will change any definitions.  It's up to you to keep track of what does what.  I would strongly suggest that you separate your definitions from your text.  Always `\input` your definitions, and `\include` your text as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Real life example: Here's the main document of my Phd thesis, I will not explain the details, I just want to show the idea.

```
%% Kommandozeilenaufruf in texmaker
% pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --extra-mem-top=60000000 %.tex|"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 9.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf

% Vorspann
% ----------------------------------------------
    \input{01_Vorspann/Dokumentenklasse.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Seitenlayout.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/WeitereLayoutAnpassungen.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Standardpakete.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Mathezeugs.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/GleitumgebungenUndVerzeichnisseAnpassen.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/KopfUndFusszeile.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Schriften_und_Symbole_Typografie.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Bibliografie-Zeugs.tex}

    \input{01_Vorspann/WeiterePakete.tex}

%   % Neu
%   % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64188/what-are-good-ways-to-make-pdflatex-output-copy-and-pasteable
%   \usepackage{cmap}

    % Zum Schluss laden!
    \input{01_Vorspann/PDF-Zeugs.tex}

% ----------------------------------------------

% Eigene Einstellungen
% ----------------------------------------------
    \input{01_Vorspann/BezeichnungenAnpassen.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Styleguide_EigeneBefehle_und_Farbdefinitionen.tex}
    \input{01_Vorspann/Trennmuster.tex}
% ----------------------------------------------

\myVersionMitAnmerkungen{off}

% Eigentliches Dokument
% ----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

    % Bookmark-Formatierung initialisieren
    \bookmarksetup{style=myBookmarkNormal}

    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \input{02_Inhalt/Titelseite.tex}
    \cleardoublepage

    % Kopf- und Fußzeile einschalten
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    % Römische (xii) Nummerierung   
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    % Zählung beginnt hier ab 1
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \input{02_Inhalt/Vorwort.tex}
    \input{02_Inhalt/Danksagung.tex}
    \input{02_Inhalt/Kurzfassung.tex}
    \input{02_Inhalt/Verzeichnisse.tex}

    \cleardoublepage    
    % Arabische (12) Nummerierung   
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    % Zählung beginnt hier wieder ab 1
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Einleitung.tex}

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/StandDerForschung.tex}     

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Haptik.tex}            

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Statistik.tex} 

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Psychophysik.tex}  

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Versuchsaufbau.tex}    

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Experimente.tex}           

    % Letzes 'richtiges' Kapitel
    % Stopp der Zwischen-TOCs
    \stopcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Zusammenfassung.tex}

    \input{02_Inhalt/Literaturverzeichnis.tex}  

    \input{02_Inhalt/Anhang.tex}

\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------
```

If I am working on a chapter, let's say statistics (`\input{02_Inhalt/Statistik.tex}`), then it would look like this:

```
%   \startcontents[chapters]
%   \input{02_Inhalt/StandDerForschung.tex}     
%   
%    \startcontents[chapters]
%   \input{02_Inhalt/Haptik.tex}            

    \startcontents[chapters]
    \input{02_Inhalt/Statistik.tex} 

%   \startcontents[chapters]
%   \input{02_Inhalt/Psychophysik.tex}  
%   
%   \startcontents[chapters]
%   \input{02_Inhalt/Versuchsaufbau.tex}
```

There are other solutions as well, for example, to put `\end{document}` in a different position (higher).

Comment: I'm not sure if this (or any) answer will help OP.  But you should look into the `\include` command (see the link further up on this page).  If you use `\input` in your preamble and `\include` in your document, you'd be able to add `\includeonly` to the preamble to automatically comment out chapters you aren't working on.  As a bonus, the numbering would still work properly.

Comment: Include adds a page break which I personally dislike. But I see your point. Anyway, the OP seems to be not interested anymore.