# How should I split/break up large LyX files?

Tags: lyx, best-practices

I have a large LyX file that sometimes gets slow (the output PDF is over 1600 pages with figures, etc.). (Indeed, with LyX 2.3.x it is somehow unbearable and [buggy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441680/) for me, and so I have stuck with 2.2.3.)

How should I split/break it up, so that I can work on a small subset of the entire document at each time, while still being able to output the entire PDF whenever I want to?

Same question but for LaTeX in general: [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/)

Comment: Haven't tested this, but maybe it's an option to put the complete preamble in a seperate .tex file. Then add `\input{preamble.tex}` within settings, under Preamble. Also use the button "Save as document details" within the settings window.  I think this makes it possible to edit parts using input and include (I assume you are already doing this). With the same preamble and settings added to inputted .tex files, I think in most cases, the parts can be  saved as seperate pdf output documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu <kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Child document</kbd> → Select the (1) filename and (2) the type of include.  (warning: This is for the 2.3.1 versión, so maybe the option is in another submenu in 2.2.3, but I am pretty sure that you will find somewhere in the insert menu).

After accept the changes (press <kbd>Ok</kbd>) you can check with <kbd>View</kbd> →  <kbd>Code Preview Pane</kbd> that this operation will insert the corresponding `\input{}` or `\include{}` LaTeX commands,  but unlike use directly that commands in an ERT box, this way you can work with child documents **in both LaTeX or LyX formats**. Of course, in both cases the resulting LaTeX code of the main file will use only the LaTeX version (see image below), i.e., if you working child file is `mychildfile.lyx` the code will show `\input{mychildfile.tex}`, not `\input{mychildfile.lyx}` that obviously cannot work.  Note that a right-click in the resulting box `Input: mychildfile.lyx` allow you to change the type of include or edit the child file.

[image]

On the other hand, if you want to use `\includeonly{}` that David mention in the comments, write it directly in <kbd>Documents</kbd> → <kbd>Settings...</kbd> → <kbd>Latex Preamble</kbd> just as explained in the answer of Bob.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with JohanFit who commented just prior to this post. Use the `\input{file}` and `\include{file}` commands. The former can be used with any other .tex file and these can be nested in the files that are input in this way. Use the `\include{file}` command for chapters and the like.

The `\input{file}` command can *indeed* be used for the preamble, and even within the preamble. The `\include{file}` command can neither appear in the preamble nor can it be nested.

To process smaller parts of a document in which you use `\include{file}`, the command `\includeonly{file_list}`, filenames separated by commas, in the preamble will process only those included files from the list. This also maintains numbering of chapters, figures, etc while only producing a portion of the document. The source file(s) are processed in the normal way to generate a typeset document - from Lyx or any other editing environment.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question which is how to be able to process smaller parts of of a document.  The answer might be `\include` and `\includeonly` but the question asks how to use it from  lyx

Comment: To process smaller parts of a document in which you use \include{file}, the command \includeonly{file list separated by commas} in the preamble will process only those included files from the list. This also maintains numbering of chapters, figures, etc while only producing a portion of the document. The source file(s) are processed in the normal way to generate a typeset document - from Lyx or any other editing environment.

Comment: I know that but why isn't that the the main part of the answer:-)  Also is it clear how to use `\includeonly` from lyx  which generally hides tex syntax (I don't use lyx so I can't say about that)

Comment: From www.lyx.org/Features:  "Access to all LaTeX functionality with capability to insert plain LaTeX code anywhere in a document. "