# How to organize a thesis?

Tags: thesis

I am new to Latex, but I am determined to learn it. I am writing my M.Sc thesis. I have found an introductory document on how to do so. My understanding is that:

1) The book class is more appropriate.

2) Apparently, it is good to break the thesis into chucks and "assemble it" with a "master file." I am a bit confused by this. I would greatly appreciate if someone could please refer me to additional info on how to write/assemble a thesis. So far, I have learned how to write small papers with math/text. Btw, my university no longer has a Latex format: they simply told me to follow the guidelines.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Nicola Talbot has written a book about writing a thesis with LaTeX, it is available for free at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/index.html (along with some other material).  I guess that may be of interest.

Comment: See also [Writing and Managing Thesis in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29531/writing-and-managing-thesis-in-latex?rq=1)