# Best documentclass to use for a dissertation/thesis

Tags: document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX templates for writing a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis)

Is there a canonical documentclass for theses? I can see some Unis offer their own templates but they also include some advanced packages I have no knowledge of...

Comment: A lot depends on whether you are in Europe (fairly free guidelines) or the US (extremely strict guidelines.)  Other parts of the world may be in between.  See [LaTeX templates for writing a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326/2693).

Comment: I am in Europe. The linked question is useful as a "list of templates", I guess I was being narrower, more "focussed?", in my request: what's the most typical one? I ask to have the greatest chance of finding helpful material around a frequently used template....

Comment: I think the basic answer then is use one of the more comprehensive classes, `memoir` or the KOMA classes.  Both are excellent for large documents.  See [What are the strengths and weaknesses of KOMA-script and memoir?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7742/2693)