# What are some useful packages in lyx for writing thesis?

Tags: lyx, packages

Useful packages and how to use them.

Comment: This is too broad a question as it stands (and risks being closed as such), since there may be no unique answer that actually answers this question.

Comment: You should probably have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326/34551 Your question, as it is asked, cannot lead to any usefull answer.

Comment: Also, take a look at the "thesis" in LyX examples directory (go to File > Open then click on the "examples" button).