# How to include an image in a LaTeX class?

Tags: graphics, texmf

So I have an image and I want it to be part of the class (this is going to be a class for letters, and the image is the logo of my University).  Is it possible to configure `graphicx` so that it can include an image located somewhere in my `~/texmf` local TeXlive tree?

Comment: If you refer for instance [to that big list of templates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326/34551), I have the feeling that all "external" figures or images are located in `figures` files in the same folder as the class. It is less intrusive oand more portable.

Comment: `\DeclareGraphicsPath` does not work?

Comment: The default behaviour is to look for images on the same path as tex files/packages, so if latex can find your class it can find your images (see how the mwe package makes example images available)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\DeclareGraphicsPath` shouldn't be needed here.