# Class for my thesis (I am a beginner, just installed LaTeX)… which document class and packages should I consider?

Tags: document-classes, thesis

I am in the process of writing up a PhD thesis (Economics) in the TeXStudio environment, and I'm trying to decide what class/layout to use. I'm new to TeXStudio & LaTeX.

I must say that the documentation is too long and horrible in comparison to mathematical programming languages like R. I still do not have any idea how to get a grasp on features of packages and how to properly use it. It seems like that I have to read all those manuals consisting of >200 pages to understand what is going on... There seems to be no fast 'help' way denoting a half page summary of commands like in R.

Basically, I just want to get the format nice (as nice as I can make it). I want to blow everyone away with a beautiful style with my thesis. Maybe some old fashioned book style? Or report? Or something like memoir or something?

Can you recommend a document class I should use? I have read a bit about the memoir class, but I'm not sure if that is the best option. Alternatively, I have read about KOMA-Script classes, which are maybe another option?

Keen for your insight - because at the moment I'm not sure whether I even should use LaTeX as  I do not want any problems with licenses or something, because I want my thesis to not be licensed under anything. My thesis is my thesis. So maybe it is better to just use Word?

Comment: I would use the `article` documentclass, but it is very much up to your decision, and nobody can decide instead of you.

Comment: @bmv `article` is not for thesis, it is for smaller documents, `book` is more suitable.

Comment: I think this post could be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex

Comment: Also this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis

Comment: @CarLaTeX   Problem is that templates are licensed..

Comment: Well, the nice thing about LaTeX is that the content and the format are independent (**if** you write correct LaTeX, avoiding visual hacks). I would say --- follow @CarLaTeX answer, and write the thesis. You can change the format almost on the spot later. If you want a "one stop" format, look at `memoir`, the doc is also very well done and enjoyable.

Comment: @Frank all standard classes are open source (most are LPPL the same as latex) I'm not aware of any classes the use of which implies any restrictions on the use of the resulting document. That isn't to say they do not exist, can  you link an example?

Comment: @Frank I feel your pain. I've learned ten programming languages, and all had a better "getting started" story than LaTeX. I never was able to internalize anything beyond the typesetting of mathematical expressions.

Comment: Obviously "better documented" is a relative notion, but as both an R user and a LaTeX user, my experience has been that R documentation (and package syntax) is much worse that most LaTeX documentation. For an absolute beginner, I would actually buy a book. Marc van Dongen's *LaTeX and Friends* (Springer, 2012) is very good and up to date.  The advantage of `memoir` is that you can do almost everything within the class. The disadvantage with `memoir` is that you can do almost everything within the class. I wouldn't use KOMA simply because IMO the English documentation is unreadable.

Comment: @Frank You can also try slightly different approach. Download all-in-once, learn on-the-fly. I think any problem, you are about to face, was already solved here. Maybe having a `sandbox.tex` somewhere to test new solutions to new problems will be useful.

Comment: @AlanMunn: The German version of KOMA's manual isn't better, in my point of view ;-)

Comment: Many universities will have their own thesis class.  Here's the first one that popped up in a search: https://oit.colorado.edu/software-hardware/tex-latex/thesis-class

Comment: @jamesqf Absoluely! If possible, try to see if your university already has a template or similar which you can use.

Comment: Not an answer, but IMHO learning LaTeX by reading the documentation is will do nothing but make your brain shrivel up; Find a simple template and just start writing, searching online for solutions to problems as you go along. That being said, some packages which are indispensable are `booktabs`, `graphicx`, `inputenc`, `fontenc` and either `natbib` or `biblatex`.

Comment: @Frank It might be worth asking a separate question about licensing if you're concerned about that, but in general I don't think this is a problem you can save yourself from by using e.g. Word. Both LaTeX and Word, as well as most other document authoring systems one might use for a thesis, use templates and styles and fonts and other _potentially_ license-encumbered elements "behind the scenes".

Comment: @David Z: IANAL, but even if some parts of the LaTeX toolchain did have licenses (which to the best of my knowledge they don't), I don't see how that would affect the finished product.  It's used for a great many scientific publications (I'd guess a majority), with no reported problems.

Comment: @jamesqf For the most part I don't see how they would either, but I think that point is off topic and best left for a separate question. I only really wanted to make the point that the license issue seems unrelated to what's being asked here.

Answer (score 47):

Don't worry about the length of package documentation, you don't need to read everything!

If you use just the packages present in TeX Live (or MiKTeK or any other official distribution), I don't think you have license problems.

If your faculty already has a template, use it.

If not, just start with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{front-page.tex}

\include{dedication.tex}

\tableofcontents{}

\mainmatter
\include{introduction.tex}

\include{chapter-1.tex}

\include{...}

\include{conclusions.tex}

\include{bibliography.tex}

\backmatter
...
\end{document}
```

and in every `.tex` file put the relative content (for the difference between `\include` and `\input`, see here: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)).

In your preamble, load your packages, I use:

in general:

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% linguistic package
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

to set the page margin:

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

to set headers and footers:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

if you have some math formulae:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

if you have some tables:

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% for having numbers aligned to the decimal point
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

for figure and table captions:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

if you have some graphics:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

(to include external images - and not only - also not made in LaTeX)

and

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

(if you like to draw your graphics directly in LaTeX)

for the bibliography:

```
\usepackage{biblatex} % or any other you like
```

for hyperlinks:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Of course, you'll have to refine their options to your needs.

Then add other packages only if you need them.

Taking a look at [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) or another guide listed here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) is surely useful.

When your thesis will be finished, you could use `beamer` documentclass to create the presentation for its defense.

For any problem, we are here to help.

*If you have no time to learn and you are full of doubt, just use Word (even if LaTeX is MUCH better).*

```
\begin{wackynote}
```

Eventually, as marmot said in chat, nowadays it is virtually impossible to write a proper thesis without samcarter's `tikzducks` package.

```
\end{wackynote}
```

Comment: I have a couple of months to prepare my thesis, so I want to explore LaTeX and use it as it seems to be much better than Word.

Is it bad to use MikTex? Should I switch to TeXLive?

Comment: @Frank Please try, then! Go little step by little step. Read "A short guide to LaTeX" to begin, look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner! Happy TeXing!

Comment: @Frank The main differences between MiKTeX and TeX Live are 1) TeX Live install all the package one for all whereas MiKTeX has the on-the-fly installation. 2) TeX Live is managed by TUG. For the rest they are more or less the same. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex. I had used MiKTeX for many year but switched to TeX Live because MiKTeX server sometimes is down.

Comment: @CarLaTeX MikTeX has options to install "on-th-fly" and "all-in-one". The second one is what I prefer. I would also recommend looking at `beamer` for presentation.

Comment: @Crowley Yes, I know, I used MiKTeX for years, I only highlighted the differences. I'll add a note for `beamer`.

Comment: Hrm. Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5763

Comment: What does `\begin{wackynote}` mean?

Comment: @Ooker It's only a joke. Look at `tikzducks` package and you'll understand :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yes. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Ran out of space in the comment sections, so posting this as an answer instead.

I used `memoir` as the backbone of my thesis. It worked great, but it might be a bit much for a beginner. If you really want to use it to its potential (and if you don't, you probably don't need it, and the default classes make more sense), studying at least some parts of the manual is probably required. It's a big (and good) manual, so since you mention you'd like to avoid extensive reading of manuals, it might not be quite the right tool for the job here.

The `book` or `report` class are potentially more sensible starting points. Some of their finer points which might be of interest, and differences to the `article` class, can be found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36989/131649).

Lists with generally recommended packages have already been linked by others, so I'll avoid repeating those here. In general, I would recommend not overdoing it with the packages. Start out with the minimum, then add packages if you really need them -- don't just dump 50 packages into your preamble without knowing what they're for or if you even need them (you probably don't).

Also, make sure you know the requirements of your institution for your document, and try to incorporate those from the start (e.g. How does the bibliography need to be formatted? Does the document have to fulfill accessibility requirements for PDF/A? Does your thesis advisor have any special requests/demands? Etc.). Patching them in after you've already done a lot of work can be rather tricky, so it's good to get an early start on this. I was lucky in this regard; our college gave us a lot of freedom. But I know that the requirements in other institutions can be rather more exact. Some even have their own templates -- if yours does, probably best to use that.

As for licensing: The content which is created by you does not need to be licensed at all, or can be licensed under another license than the [LPPL](https://www.latex-project.org//lppl/) -- I licensed my thesis under the MIT license, for example. As long as you stick to default packages from your distribution, you should be fine. If you use packages or templates from other sources, make sure to check the licensing though.

Lastly: Don't panic about reading documentation too much. You almost never need to read all of it, and as you get more acquainted with (La)TeX in general, you'll also get better at finding the important bits which matter for your particular use case. It might make sense to check out some beginner-friendly resources though -- [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/131649) might have something of interest on that front.

Comment: I'm currently using memoir for my thesis and I like it, but for a beginner I'm not sure I'd recommend it. It does a lot of things differently to "normal" latex, so some googled solutions won't work on a memoir document.

Comment: @CharlieB Yeah, agreed. I spent a lot of time in `memman.pdf` when I wrote my class on top of it. It's a great manual, and I'm happy with the result of my efforts, but many an hour was sunk into that undertaking. It's probably not the path I'd recommend to a newcomer unless they were explicitly asking about going down such a path.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend two things:

1. Learn the basics of LaTeX by reading *The Not So Short Introduction to Latex.* ("https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf"). I know it is a long book, exactly what you said you didn't want -- but you only need to read chapters 2 and 3. Further, it will go quickly (90 mins tops), and LaTeX is something you should know if you're getting a PhD in STEM.
2. For a thesis, don't start from scratch -- no need to reinvent the wheel. Ask if your university has a template; if not, you can use one from a different university and just modify things until it's compliant. Here is the one from UCSB: http://www.graddiv.ucsb.edu/docs/default-source/academic-services-documents/dissertationtemplatelatexc0f10ec1cf8b6fd1a50fff0000c25041.zip?sfvrsn=0

As others have said, licensing will not be a problem (and I hardly think the solution to concerns about licensing would be to use a Microsoft product!).

Answer (score 4):

Being biased (as the original author of `memoir`) I recommend using `memoir`. Very simply you can use it just like the standard `book` class, which is a good starting point for a thesis, but it also includes many commonly desired extensions and enhancements which are there if you want them. I admit that the documentation is long but you only have to read the portions that are relevant to you.

I don't know what your institution's thesis layout requirements are (I get the impression that every institution's is unique and all are mutually incompatible) but the documentation does include a complete example of the code for a not-untypical thesis which you may find useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially correct. Most packages don't have the equivalent of a "quick start guide", just the standard documentation (which may get quite technical, for some packages).

I think most people learn to use Latex with (1) a book or a guide aimed to beginners, and (2) "by examples", reading and modifying a lot of other people's code. This is where they pick up lots of bad habits such as `{\it this one}`.

Comment: I don't think `\em` is a bad habit unlike the deprecated font commands such as `\it`. It's defined in the LaTeX kernel using `\DeclareRobustCommand` (not `\DeclareOldFontCommand`).

Comment: @yudai-nkt Thanks - -- I did not know there was a difference between them. I have changed the example, with `\it` it should be more unanimous that it is a bad habit.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question or a comment? Because the question seems to be about document class and packages...