# Appendix numeration

Tags: appendix

I am finishing my thesis and I run into the following problem.

The appendix enumeration does not differ from the figure enumeration. The following figure could help to understand what I am trying to explain:
[image: appendix numbering]

I want the enumeration of the appendix to be different from the enumeration of the thesis content.

I am currently working with the following template:

```
% ===== INICIO DEL PREÁMBULO =====
%
\documentclass[dsc,oneside,a4paper]{udelar} % Poner msc para Maestría, dsc para Doctorado.
%
\usepackage[
acronyms,                                            %utiliza el glosario de acronimos.
nohypertypes={acronym,notacion,simbolos,glosario},   %quita los links en el texto al glosario.
%nonumberlist,                                       %quita los links en los glosarios al texto.
nogroupskip,                                         %quita los espacios entre diferentes grupos dentro de un glosario.
nopostdot,                                           %quita el punto final en los acrónimos         .                         
]{glossaries}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks = true } % Hipervínculos: escribir "false" para imprimir o "true" para ver en digital.

% Ver los documentos de estilos bibliográficos para editar estas siguientes 2 líneas. Se deben de copiar a partir de los PDF de estilos bibliográficos y no es necesario que el estudiante las edite.
\usepackage{natbib} % Para algunos estilos bibliográficos
\bibliographystyle{estilos_bibliograficos/natbib/apalike}

\loadglossary % No comentar esta línea
\raggedbottom
% A su vez, la clase udelar.cls ya tiene los siguientes paquetes cargados automáticamente, que podrían ser de interés saber para el usuario:
% 
% {color},{hyphenat},{appendix},{lastpage},{babel},{inputenc},{amsmath,amssymb},{ifthen},{graphicx},{caption}
% {setspace},{tabularx},{eqparbox},{ltxcmds},{titletoc},{xcolor},{lineno},{xwatermark}

% Si se quieren agregar más paquetes, se recomienda colocarlos a partir de esta linea y antes de \begin{document}.
% ===========  INICIO PAQUETES ===============
\usepackage{siunitx}% paquete para manejo de números y unidades
\usepackage{overpic}% figuras
\usepackage{graphicx}% para gráficos
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
% ===========   FIN PAQUETES   ===============

% Definición de correctores, con un máximo de tres correctores.
\definechangesauthor[color=redtex]{JLM}         % Siglas del primer corrector 
\definechangesauthor[color=bluetex]{JH}         % Siglas del segundo corrector
\definechangesauthor[color=greentex]{MC}        % Siglas del tercer corrector

% =====  FIN DEL PREÁMBULO  =====

% ===== INICIO DEL DOCUMENTO =====

\begin{document}

  \date{23}{10}{2019}

  \keyword{Lutitas Pirobituminosas}
  \keyword{Residuos de biomasa}
  \keyword{Cinética química}
  \keyword{Co-combustión}
  \keyword{Energía}

  \maketitle  
  \frontmatter  
  \include{ded_agr_epi/dedicacion}
  \include{ded_agr_epi/agradecimientos}
  \include{ded_agr_epi/epigrafe}
  \include{resumen/resumen}

  \listoffigures             % Lista de figuras
  \listoftables              % Lista de tablas
  \listadesimbolos           % Lista de símbolos
  \listadesiglas             % Lista de siglas
  \tableofcontents           % Tabla de contenidos. 
  \mainmatter 

  \include{capitulos/chap01} % Se carga el capítulo 01
  \include{capitulos/chap02} % Se carga el capítulo 02
  \include{capitulos/chap03} % Se carga el capítulo 03
  \include{capitulos/chap04} % Se carga el capítulo 04



  \backmatter

  \bibliography{bibliografia/biblio_1,bibliografia/biblio_2,bibliografia/biblio_3} 
  \bibend 

  \apenarabicnumbering
  \apenmatter               
  \input{apendice/apendice_A}
  \input{apendice/apendice_B}
  \anexarabicnumbering
  \anexmatter                
  \input{anexo/anexo_A}
  \input{anexo/anexo_B}

\end{document}

% ===== FIN DEL DOCUMENTO =====
```

Comment: Please, it is so important. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please prepare a complete and self contained example document (see also [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  that others can use to recreate the issue you describe. Currently, your example code loads a lot of files that we don't have access to. Please also explain "different from the enumeration of the thesis content". How exactly should the numbering scheme of the appendix figures look like? Please clarify.

Comment: We cant test your document example since we haven't files which you  include in documents. Replace them with only chapter or section titles. Also used document class seems not to be public (available). Please reduce your preamble to only necessary packages/definitions which reproduce your problem. BTW, `hyperref` package should be loaded lat in preamble.

Comment: Though files are not included and code cannot be tested I feel the problem is with the input command taking the file as it is --I hope the numbering is not pre-included in the file--please see the difference between input and include on this site--[link]https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409664/197451[link]