# Good MSc Thesis Proposal Templates on Overleaf?

Tags: templates, thesis

I need to write an MSc thesis proposal, and I can't seem to find any good templates for such. Do you guys know of any good templates? It's urgent :)

Comment: Use the article class.

Comment: If it's really, really urgent... maybe you should use Microsoft Word?

Comment: @LianTzeLim ew no, gross... That's heresy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX templates for writing a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326/latex-templates-for-writing-a-thesis)

Comment: @gman Brandon asks for a template to write a proposal, not the actual thesis, at this moment

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Don't forget, it's a new user!

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin yeah I have a nice template that I am using for my thesis, but I can't find any templates for a thesis proposal

Comment: @BrandonBattye I stripped out the content from the file I used. I added the code to the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully managed to do my MSc thesis on the subject I wanted to discuss, with the professor I liked, with the help of a company I liked, by submitting a proposal written using the [`tufte-latex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) class.

I guess however that it's not the documentclass, rather the content of your proposal, that will help you to nail it!

In any case, the tufte-latex class is very nice (even though it appears that it's not under active development -- but for your needs it should do the job).

Here's an example to make you started ;)

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,twoside,sfsidenotes,openany,final]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title[]{title of proposal}
\author[Your Name]{Your Name}
\publisher{thesis proposal}
\date{}

% --new title page--

\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}[0]{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  {%
  \sffamily%
  \begin{fullwidth}%
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{21}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}%
  \vfill%
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}}%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  }
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage%
}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Background}

\newthought{Here} you provide basic background about the subject of your thesis\sidenote{Interesting insight on the work you want to carry on.}, providing also some essential references\cite{Knu86}.

\section{Proposal}

\newthought{Here} you state your proposal, along with some essential references of the methods, techniques you want to use.
\begin{marginfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{}
    \caption{some interesting figure}
    \label{fig:Huang1995a}
\end{marginfigure}

State clearly the objectives you want to achieve.

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{\jobname} % if you’re using BibTeX
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me man!